# AngularJS one way binding component trigger 'Invalid controller bindings definition for directive'

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-components

I am getting this weird error when applying binding in an angular component:

> Error: [$compile:iscp] Invalid controller bindings definition for directive 'workTimekeepingsDay'. Definition: {... timekeepings: '<' ...}

Here is the code:

```
<work-timekeepings-day timekeepings="dailyTimekeepingCtrl.timekeepingList  | timekeepingDay : dailyTimekeepingCtrl.selectedDay" day="dailyTimekeepingCtrl.selectedDay"></work-timekeepings-day>

var workTimekeepingsDay = TimekeepingsApp.component('workTimekeepingsDay', {
        templateUrl : 'angular/components/work-timekeepings-day.html',
        controllerAs: '$workTkDayCtrl',
        bindings : {
            timekeepings : '<',
            day: '='
        }
});
```

HTML template:

```
<div class="row lightgreen-row padding-5 border-rounded" ng-repeat-start="workTk in $workTkDayCtrl.timekeepings | timekeepingDay : day">
    <div class="col-md-4"> <b> {{ workTk.user.firstName + ' ' + workTk.user.lastName }} </b> </div>
```

What is wrong with 'timekeepings' binding?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also go this error, but it was due to using a 1.5.0 RC version of angular.  Updating to the latest version of angular fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Yep, That was the fix. Thanks.